# Rule my 'hover' function with an if statement - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to show an image ('.tirellidrop') with a slide effect, on hover (or mouseover). Then, when the image is shown, if I click on my container, I'll have another slideToggle.

Everything works, but when my second slide is visible, I don't want the hover function to work.

So:

1. I move the mouse on my element ---> '.tirellidrop' slides out.
2. I click on the element -----> '.ttx_rosso' slides out AND '.tirellidrop' remains visible until I click again on the element.

I added a class called "visibile", and I wrote: IF my element does NOT have this class, you can slide my image on hover. Then, if I click on the element and I get my second function, this shouldn't happen again. But it does.

```
if(!$('.ttx_rosso').hasClass('visibile')) {

    $(".tr_rosso").hover(function () {
        $(".tirellidrop").slideToggle("400");
    }, function () {
        $(".tirellidrop").slideToggle("400");
    });
}


$('.tr_rosso').click(function() {
    $(".ttx_rosso").slideToggle("slow").toggleClass('visibile');
});
```

Look just at the first red element: http://codepen.io/GCW/pen/myVwXP/

Comment: try searching for "stop propagation" and "prevent default"

Comment: I know about stop propagation, but I can't anyway solve this problem